# Why have an internal constructor that does nothing special?

Tags: c#

This is a spin off of [this closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404425/why-the-extra-step), I had an answer but it was closed before I could respond. Here is a tweaked version of the question:

Why would a class have a internal constructor that just sets properties?

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass() : this(new SomeOtherClass()) { }
    internal SomeClass(SomeOtherClass c) { _someField = c; }

    private SomeOtherClass _someField;

    protected void SomeMethod() {
        var foo = _someField.Bar();
    }
}
```

What is the benefit of this, why would you not just do:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass() { _someField = new SomeOtherClass(); }

    private SomeOtherClass _someField;

    protected void SomeMethod() {
        var foo = _someField.Bar();
    }
}
```

Comment: This pattern is also referred to as *Poor Man's Dependency Injection* - a total anti-pattern.

Comment: It can also be used when you have special internal usage/creation of your class within your assembly/library, but want to expose a different/constrained method for third parties to consume.  In this case, perhaps you have an internal factory that can pass in existing instances of `SomeOtherClass` to be used. But if a third party wants to create a `SomeClass`, they _must_ use the default constructor and have it create a new instance of `SomeOtherClass`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having a `protected` or `internal` constructor like this is very common for this is doing testing with [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

When you call the code normally it just creates a instance of `SomeOtherClass` however when you run your unit tests you can have it pass a mocked version of `SomeOtherClass` that simulates it (lets say `SomeOtherClass` is your data layer interface and `SomeClass` is your business logic layer class, the mocked class fakes the calls to the DB and returns the results as if it was connected to the DB)

```
internal class UnitTest
{
    [Fact]
    public TestDbInterface()
    {
        var someClass = new SomeClass(new MockedSomeOtherClass())

        var result = someClass.SomeMethod()

        Assert.AreEqual("42", result);
    }
}
```

This allows you to do unit testing without doing expensive operations like setting up to a known state and running a full database server on the test machine to test against for tests not directed at classes for the data layer.

Comment: Too bad everyone wanted to close my question before you came along. Oh well, thanks for the explanation :)